# Neo4j to load parquet file: Multiple element with the same key found, but the element type is not a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher, parquet

I am trying to read and load a parquet file data to neo4j, below is the schema of my parquet file:

```
root
 |-- globalcustid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- member_node: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- label: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- properties: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- relationships: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- node: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- relationship: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is one row of my parquet data (displayed in json format for better readability):

```
{
    "globalcustid": "12345",
    "member_node": {
        "label": "MEMBER",
        "properties": [
            {
                "key": "age",
                "value": "45"
            },
            {
                "key": "gender",
                "value": "Male"
            }
        ]
    }
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationship": {
                "label": "LIVE_IN",
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "key": "createdate",
                        "value": "2023-11-22"
                        },
                    {
                        "key": "enddate",
                        "value": "9999-12-31"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "node": {
                "label": "COUNTRY",
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "key": "country_id",
                        "value": "c123"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "country_name",
                        "value": "us"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my cypher script to load the file:

```
call apoc.load.parquet(
    'part-00000-183a44db-1c2a-4e98-9db2-6aefaa419751-c000.snappy.parquet',
    {
        batchSize: 50000,
        mapping: {
                globalcustid: 'Varchar', member_node: 'MAP', relationships: 'LIST'
        }
    }
) yield value as row

return *
```

However, it returned the following error. But the key values are unique in the properties array.

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.parquet`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple element with the same key found, but the element type is not a list
```

Comment: Do any of your `properties` arrays have multiple elements with the same `key` values?

Comment: @cybersam Hi, I checked that the key values are unique in the properties array